# React Native If Statement Not Functioning properly with State

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have created this function in react native:

```
confirmOTP(){
  console.log(this.state.otpEntry)
  console.log(this.state.sixDigitauth)
  if (this.state.otpEntry === this.state.sixDigitauth){
    this.setState({
      modalVisibility: false
    })
    console.log ("authenticated")
  }else{
    console.log ("incorrect OTP")
  }
}
```

Although the function console logs both `this.state.otpEntry` and `this.state.sixDigitauth` and the text in them matches, I still end up getting a console log of "incorrect OTP". This means that the if statement is unable to match both states.
`464042 464042 incorrect OTP`

Both data types are text:
`this.state = {         sixDigitauth: '', otpEntry: '', }`

Any idea why?

thanks in advance

Comment: they need to be equal

Comment: from their names, I suspect they're supposed to be numbers. Are you sure theyre both of the same datatype?

Comment: Probably a problem with datatypes or whitespace trim

Comment: @PatrykCieszkowski yes should be..

Comment: @ShadabSiddiqui what is whitespace trim?

Comment: If it's type is string, then just check if you are not getting any spaces in pre and Post part of string, for both the variables

Comment: @kerimErkan can you add this line above your if statement and let us know what it says? `console.log({ otpEntry: typeof this.state.otpEntry, sixDigitauth: typeof this.state.sixDigitauth })` -- This will let us be sure about what data-types the values are. They could be either strings or numbers and they might look the same, but they're not `===`.

Comment: this.state.otpEntry.trim() === this.state.sixDigitAuth.trim()

Comment: Try above line to check if it's work

Comment: @ShadabSiddiqui it won't work. A triple equal checks for datatype, so unless theyre both strings - the check will fail. Plus, Number doesnt have a trimp method, so it will fail up there as well. @kerim Erikan If both values are of type String/Number, you can place a `+` sign in front of them, which will convert them to Number and get rid of any potential whitespaces.

Comment: "Both data types are text: `this.state = { sixDigitauth: '', otpEntry: '', }`" This appears to be a true statement when initializing state, but have you confirmed this as a fact throughout the component lifecycle? What updates these states over time? As said above, log the types just before the conditional. Check the values when trimmed.

Comment: his state object for those variables are in string form , probably it's not number may be, and even doing trim on those variables will let know it's type is not string by throwing error on number doesn't contain any trim method

Comment: @PatrykCieszkowski i believe the + should work but im unsure where and how to place it. Could you clarify it please

Comment: @kerimErkan sure, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like you have a mismatch of datatypes, and since a `triple equal` sign attempts to match variables on their content, as well as their type - it returns `false`, hence your query fails.

You have a couple of options:

1. Add a `+` sign in front of the variables. It will convert them to a `Number` type:

```js
  confirmOTP(){
    if (+this.state.otpEntry === +this.state.sixDigitauth) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  }
```

2. Replace a `===` sign, with `==` sign. I don't recommend it, but it will technically solve the problem.

```js
  confirmOTP(){
    if (this.state.otpEntry == this.state.sixDigitauth) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  }
```

3. You could also make sure they're in appropriate datatypes, at the moment of updating the state:

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      otpEntry: +props.otpEntry
      sixDigitauth: +props.sixDigitauth
    }
  }
```

Make sure to catch up on some theory.

equations:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

unary plus:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus

Comment: option 1 (adding the + sign) worked perfectly. It turns out that as you mentioned, the random number generator I created is in numeric datatype while the data entry by the user is a string. Thank Patryk!